# Coarse heat map placement using gdal

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I have generated a coarse heatmap of where data is available by 1 degree x 1 degree cells that I want to overlay on top of a world image.  Using a python script I merged two images (heat map and a world map -- generated with gdal_rasterize).

Reviewing the picture I have a vertical registration issue (I am guessing a flattening issue).   The picture can be sent if needed but I cannot post it at this time (I do not have a reputation >= 10).

How can I use gdal to merge these images correctly?

Thanks